Printing scientific format notation
1st code
void solve()
{
    ll n; 
    cin >> n;
    vector <ll> v(n);
    ld sum = 0;
    ld mx = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> v[i];
    }
         while (v.size() > 1) {
            
            sort(v.begin(), v.end());
 
            int i = 0, j = 1; 
 
            ld ac = (v[i] + v[j]) / 2;
 
       
           sum += v[i] + v[j];
           
            v.erase(v.begin() + j); 
            v.erase(v.begin() + i);
 
            v.push_back(ac);
        }
 
        cout << floor(v[0]) << "\n";
}

when I am submitting 1st code the output is in scientific notation when number is large.
But when I removed floor function output is in integer? Why?
ChatGpt sayingenter image description here
The code got accepted when I remove floor is here :
void solve()
{
    ll n; 
    cin >> n;
    vector <ll> v(n);
   
    ld mx = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> v[i];
    }
         while (v.size() > 1) {
            
            sort(v.begin(), v.end());
 
            int i = 0, j = 1; 
 
            ld ac = (v[i] + v[j]) / 2;
 
       
  
           
            v.erase(v.begin() + j); 
            v.erase(v.begin() + i);
 
            v.push_back(ac);
        }
 
        cout <<v[0] << "\n";
}

Problem link is here : https://codeforces.com/contest/2021/problem/A
I know this problem is a better and short solution. And I do that. But my curious mind want to know this I told here. And I also know there are some unneccesary data type used. But here in
 ld ac = (v[i] + v[j]) / 2;

is calculating in long long or int because v[i] and v[j] are long long or int. And ac is storing in vector which has long long data type. I think there is no floating point arithemtic occured here which ChatGpt was said.

std::floor returns a floating point number not an integer.  When doing integer maths do not use floating point functions as you will most likely lose accuracy.

Unrelated: Don't use ll etc. Use the proper types so that we know what you mean.

You should first and foremost read the documentation. Trust yourself to make your own thoughts rather than letting ChatGPT think for you. Then you will see that floor returns a floating point number and that is the reason for the behavior you experienced.

floor returns float or double (screenshot taken from the documentation in the link and the content is pasted as code below it)

float       floor ( float num );

double      floor ( double num );
long double floor ( long double num );
    (until C++23)
constexpr /* floating-point-type */
            floor ( /* floating-point-type */ num );
    (since C++23)
float       floorf( float num );
    (2)     (since C++11)
(constexpr since C++23)
long double floorl( long double num );
    (3)     (since C++11)
(constexpr since C++23)
Additional overloads (since C++11)
        
Defined in header <cmath>
        
template< class Integer >
double      floor ( Integer num );
    (A)     (constexpr since C++23)

Quoting the return summary:

If no errors occur, the largest integer value not greater than num, that is ⌊num⌋, is returned.

The value is therefore logically an integer, but it is of type of float or double which is the source of your problems, because, if your value happened to be an int, then floor searches for the greatest integer infimum of your int, which is itself. So, unless you are okay with converting all your integers to float/double in the output, then don't call floor. Or, if you actually have float and double values which you want to round down, then you could convert the result of floor to int via
cout << ((int)floor(v[0])) << "\n";

which may be useful when you may have non-integers, but in this current example just avoid calling floor and refer the item as v[0].

BTW, v[0] is already of integral type, so floor is useless.

@Jarod42 thanks for pointing that out, I have edited my answer accordingly.
